# How can I simplify a function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

I consider the following function;

$$f:\{1,-1\} \times \{0,1\} \ni (a,b) \to f(a,b) \in \{1,-1\}$$

satisfying 
\begin{align*}
&f(a,b) = 1 \quad (a=1, b=0),\\
&f(a,b) = 1 \quad (a=1, b=1),\\
&f(a,b) = 1 \quad (a=-1, b=0),\\
&f(a,b) = -1 \quad (a=-1, b=1).
\end{align*}

Then would you give me some examples which simplify this function?

Comment: What do you mean simplify the function in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just $f: \{-1,1\} \times \{0,1\} \rightarrow \{-1,1\}, \ (a,b) \mapsto a^b$